# Java JNI wrapper tool

Tags: c++, dll, java-native-interface, jna, jnaerator

I'm trying to generate java code that is capable to invoke functions provided in some C++ header (*.h extension) files which are implemented by a DLL file.

I've tried cxxwrap and I got all the java classes with no compilation errors but not all methods were generated. Also tried JNAerator and although all methods were generated I got a lot of compilation errors.

Can anyone give me some advice on this issues?

Thanks

Comment: I would need to know what type of issues you need. I can comnent you some useful tools, but I don't know if you need this...

Comment: I don't need issues, I need to solved them :p

Comment: sorry,  my mistake, "what type of advices you need..."

Comment: I have successfully run JNAerator 0.12-shaded on visa.h (C only, not C++) and used its generated jar file. Who is reporting compilation errors, JNAerator or your Java code using the generated jar file?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use [swig](http://www.swig.org/) . It autogenerates all necessary wrappers...